# How to exclude certain labels when using leaflet in R?

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm making a map in R using leaflet... My data contains the columns - latitudes, longitudes, country name, region, and population. And I have set the Country name, region and population to appear as a popup label when you hover hover the point on the map.

However, not all countries in my data have associated regions (Those are NA's in my data). And I was wondering if it's possible to only show the country name and population in the popup label when hovering over those specific countries... and keep the region data intact for the countries that contain regions?

Ive outlined a very small example below, to clarify what im trying to achieve:

```
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

long <-     c(-3.436000, -4.548100)
lat <- c(55.378100, 54.236100)
pop <- c(700000, 5000)
Country <- "UK"
Region <- c(NA, "Isle of man")

dataf <- data.frame(long,lat,pop,Country,Region)

dataf %>% 
  leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite, group = "Toner Lite") %>%
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("Toner Lite")) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lng = dataf$long, lat = dataf$lat, 
                   popup=paste("Country:", dataf$Country, "<br>",
                               "Region:", dataf$Region, "<br>",
                               "Pop:", dataf$pop),
                   stroke = F, fillOpacity = 0.5) # Val False
```

if I hover over a point with a region, the map looks like this:
[image: image1]

However, if I hover over a point with no attached region, it looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to remove the region label on the popup for the data that has no associated region? whilst keeping it intact for the locations that do have regions?

Answer (score 0):

What if you just made another dataset where Region != NA, and graph those, while still keeping the original dataset in place?